# Exception when parsing RFC1123 date with HttpServletRequest#getDateHeader()

Tags: java, servlets, simpledateformat, rfc1123

I am trying to parse the HTTP header `Date: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 08:12:31 GMT` for an [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) with a call to `request.getDateHeader("Date")` but get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 08:12:31 GMT
    at org.mortbay.io.BufferUtil.toLong(BufferUtil.java:106) 
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field.getLongValue(HttpFields.java:1479)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields.getLongField(HttpFields.java:720)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getIntHeader(Request.java:728)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getIntHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:106)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getIntHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:106)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter$RequestWrapper.getDateHeader(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:417)
    at com.example.ExampleServlet.doPost(ExampleServlet.java:93)
```

What am I doing wrong? The sample date is taken directly from the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18), so I would expect it to be valid under RFC 1123. The servlet is part of an App Engine app (on development server).

Comment: Did you trim that stack trace? It doesn't contain a reference to `getDateHeader` or any code that you might have written. Could you edit your question to include the code that you wrote and a more complete stack trace?

Comment: @Kenster I've added a few more lines from the stack trace (and obfuscated my actual class name as `ExampleServlet`). As you can see, the servlet is hosted on Google App Engine. I can also post the full trace if needed. The actually call inside `doPost()` looks like this: `Date date = new Date(request.getDateHeader("Date"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a known bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8415&q=Type=Defect%20date&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) in the app engine library. [Here is the `getDateHeader` function](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/development/ResponseRewriterFilter.java?r=421#373) at issue, and it clearly calls `super.getIntHeader()`. It doesn't look like Google is in a hurry to fix it, unfortunately.

Comment: +1 My current workaround is to call `Date date = rfc1123DateFormat.parse(request.getHeader("Date"))` on a `DateFormat` that has been initialized with `rfc1123DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US); rfc1123DateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`.